# Dart/Flutter regex to only allow mixed fractions and decimals

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, decimal, fractions

How can I only allow decimal or mixed fraction values in input field in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

I am using inputFormatters for a text field in flutter and wanted to only allow the following values

- whole numbers
- mixed fractions
- decimals

The regex that allows this is as follows

```
^[0-9]+(([.]?[0-9]*)?|([ ]?[0-9]*[/]?[0-9]*)?)?
```

Note the above regex does not validate that the denominator is not 0 but that is okay for my application.

Enjoy